# Spring JpaRepositories with multiple persistence units

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a multi-module Spring application where each module (jar) contains its own persistence.xml.

In jar 1

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="pu_one" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

EntityOne.java

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne {
}
```

EntityOneRepository.class

```
interface EntityOneRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityOne, Long> {

}
```

In jar 2:
persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="pu_two" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

EntityTwo.java

```
@Entity
public class EntityTwo {
}
```

EntityTwoRepository.class

```
interface EntityTwoRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityTwo, Long> {

}
```

Then I use a org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager to put them all together.

My issue is with regards to the JpaRepositories as they are using the default persistence unit, as defined in the configuration of the DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.

Question. How to I instruct each of the repositories to use the correct persistence unit?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up of using

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.support.MergingPersistenceUnitManager
```

Instead of the

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager
```

Then all of the entities in different jars will be merged into one persistence unit. The trick was to name all persistence units the same.

However I would prefer to inform each repository what persistence unit to use, this works for now.